# C# or C++ ; It is possible to modify memory like in CE?

Tags: c#, c++, memory

It is **Possible** to modify memory like in **CE**?
Something like:

**Original**:

```
je 011D5F29
```

**Modified**:

```
jmp 011D5F6E
```

It is possible to do in **C#**?
If it's not, then it's possible in **C++**?

If it's possible in **C#** or **C++**, then send me code
Thank **you** for reading :)

Comment: I forgot to say i need to modify memory of another app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doable in C/C++. If you have a register (say in a micro controller) and you wish to read the value (since it can change outside of your code, hardware-wise), then you can

```
#define PORTBASE 0x40000000
unsigned int volatile * port = (unsigned int *) REG; 

*port = value; /* write to port */
value = *port; /* read from port */
```

[Source](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3750.html)

I am not sure it can be done in C#.

Hope that was relevant.

Comment: HIGHLY depend on operation system (You correctly give example micro controler, ancient DOS too). On most modern systems impossible. ... seems with very "hacking" can be possible in C# (disable safety etc ...), but will not work because OS